# How can git revert changes without even storing backups?

Tags: git

I'm interested in learning more about how git works internally, and the following three facts are arousing my curiosity and I need an explanation for them:

1. Git can track any changes occurring in the code and effectively revert them if needed.
2. Git stores all its data in the hidden `.git` folder.
3. The size of the `.git` folder can be (and usually is) much smaller than the total size of code files.

Since git can find out whenever the content of any file has changed, I would presume that it stores a backup copy of the last committed content of that file, so it can use it as a reference for comparison. But what confuses me is that the size of the whole `.git` the folder is too small! How could it store backups without taking enough space for that? is it using some very effective compression algorithm? Can it somehow track changes without storing backups?

Comment: So if you are "interested" what prevents doing a little reading? https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

Comment: I did and that doesn't provide a straight answer to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What happens is that git saves the different files (contents) in separate objects (Blobs) that it keeps in a compressed format. Then, when you create a revision it builds the structure (blobs and trees) that make up that revision.... say, 10000 files...that's 10000 objects (assuming they all have different content)... it will create trees for directories with pointing to other trees or the files that make it up... then the revision points to a "root" tree. Give it a try on any revision:

```
git cat-file -p HEAD
git cat-file -p HEAD^{tree}
```

Then... you modify a single file.... and add and commit. Then git will create a new blob for that modified file, git will reuse the other 9999 objects because they haven't changed and create a new revision that points to the previous one as its parent and has the new root tree.

So.... you have 20000 objects? Not really... it's just 10001 blobs... plus the trees and the revisions.

Then how is git that fast to do operations like diff/checkout? It goes into the revisions/trees/objects and finds out the IDs.... if the IDs are the same and the name of the object is the same (in the tree) then there is no difference.... same thing for checkout to move to distant revision, it only checks what has changed between revisions and then starts to change your working tree accordingly.... and given that the operations are local it feels like it's flying through it.